# The Siddur of R Yaakov Emden

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book

Is there a version of R Yaakov Emdens siddur online?
Also how is the Siddur different from the Artscroll Ashkenazi Siddur which I am more familiar with?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, R' Yaakov Emden never compiled a siddur himself, but rather, much like in the case of the Gra, siddurim have arose throughout the years "according to R' Yaakov Emden". It is important to note that there are variations of this siddur in both Nusach Ashkenaz and Sefard, so the chances of the siddur actually reflecting the nusach of R' Yaakov Emden in unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

The book is in Hebrew Books

[Here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/42759)

Comment: According to Rav Binyomin Shlomo Hamburger שליט''א, although this siddur describes itself as the siddur of Rav Yaakov Emden זצ''ל, it is a fraud as it is clearly not the nusach that Rav Yaakov Emden זצ''ל davened.

Answer (score 0):

R' Yaakov Emden's original siddur (which the one in kouty's answer is based on, although with a lot of changes and interpolations, hence Joshua Pearl's comment there) is on Hebrewbooks [here](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/19725) (weekday and Shabbos davening), [here](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/19724) (Rosh Chodesh and the yearly cycle) and [here](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/23725) (lifecycle). Its main feature is his extensive commentary, including many different facets: notes on grammar, pshat, halachah, Kabbalah, etc. (Eshkol reprinted it some years ago, and included also more commentary of his found in manuscript.)

The nusach is basically standard Ashkenaz, although there are some places where R' Yaakov adds things that aren't part of the standard nusach (such as the detailed descriptions of the korbanos), or has a nonstandard vocalization (for example, he has the reish of רבי with a sheva, instead of earlier Ashkenazic (and unchanged Sephardic) chirik.

Comment: Was the shva or chirik not standard ashkenazi at the time? Be careful about thinking modern common ashkenazi is how ashkenazi has always been.

Comment: @DoubleAA The first time it appears (in רבי ישמעאל אומר), he makes a point of noting that it's with a sheva, and refers to his sefer Luach Eresh. Looking around on Hebrewbooks, seems like earlier Ashkenazic siddurim had it with chirik (as Sephardic siddurim still do), but not with sheva.